# My site doesn't show up on google chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have my site and it looks great on FF, SF, IE8 but on google chrome it shows a blank page, but if you click on view source, it is there !!

on js console I got "Failed to load resource".

Also I have the same site on my localhost and it works great on chrome !!

My site: http://grupooak.com

take a look on chrome and if you know how to fix it , or a tool to debug it and find the issue lmk :)

Thanks !!

btw the site was developed on php (akelos framework)

Sometimes, if you try several times you can get the page, but it gets stock if you click on any link

Comment: For whatever reason, it's not seeing the body. Do a right click->inspect element to see how the dom looks to chrome.

Comment: When run through the W3C HTML validator it fails with a large number of errors.  I can't say for sure if that's what the problem is, but it certainly wouldn't help.  Can you try to fix the issues that the validator throws up and see how Chrome copes with it then? http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgrupooak.com%2Fapp%2F%3Fak%3D%2Faccount%2Fsign_in%2F

Comment: You might consider removing the banner js. All those escapes, seems the <head> of your doc is never closing. I don't think this is an appropriate question for stack overflow....

Comment: The document now is valid, and still getting the same blank page. Sometime if you try several time you can get the page on chrome, but if you click on a link it gets stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling caching and/or output encoding?

Something similar happened to me before, and it was related to the Mime type.

If that's the case, take a look at this article: http://www.dyeager.org/post/2009/01/php-xhtml-mime-type-caching

Comment: yes, The issue was with config/caching.yml akelos file, I set this false and it worked!. To big issues small fixes :)  thanks dude.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure the DOM is valid, as your html seems messy I would advise you to fix the following errors:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://grupooak.com/app/%3Fak%3D/account/sign_in/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Just a thought but try loading the page without any javascript files, and if the page loads, add one back in a t a time testing if it still loads, when you add the javascript back in and the page fails to load, let us know what that file is.

Its could be one of the following:

- Your server is failing to respond to the call, unlikely
- there is a memory leak in the javascript files, causing the brows to focus on the file which does not continue to load the file.

Reasons for this is if you go to the url: `view-source:http://grupooak.com/app/?ak=/account/sign_in/` in Google Chrome, you will see the whole response, meaning that it is something that is loaded into the browser that's the issue.

If you inspect the element of the page you will see that it stops loading loading the page after the first javascript include, try UPDATING Your Libraries versions.

Comment: I fixed all the errors and the documents is valid, but still getting a blank page on chrome

Comment: Updated, which a possible fix

Answer (score 0):

maybe fix this tag.

```
  <img style="width: 95px; height: 113px;" src="/app/images/homepage10.jpg"
```

also look at the developer tools in chrome they will point you to this error

/app/?ak=/account/sign_in/ Failed to load resource

info about developer tools
http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

Comment: I fixed that and stille getting the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have a look at [the W3C's HTML validator output](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgrupooak.com%2Fapp%2F%3Fak%3D%2Faccount%2Fsign_in%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), correct all of the errors, and try again. I guess that it will solve your issues with Chrome.

Comment: I fixed all the errors , and still getting the same blank page

Comment: Please keep the server up, so that we can see by ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

When I inspect the computed styles in chrome, the html element's height is 0. This might explain why the page is blank.

Answer (score 0):

It's your rotator script. The first argument must be a beforeLoad event object.

Comment: I took out the rotator script and still getting the same blank page